# About gradle productFlavor execute slowly

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I have multiple productFlavors, when I execute assembleRelease command,each productFlavor will execute the lift circle task.

```
productFlavors {
        A {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            resValue("string", "channel", "A")
        }
        B {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            resValue("string", "channel", "B")
        }
        C {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            resValue("string", "channel", "C")
        }
        D {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            resValue("string", "channel", "D")
        }
        E {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            resValue("string", "channel", "E")
        }
    }
```

such as:`compile`, `transformClassesWithMultidexlist`, `merge`, `generate`, `assemble`, `check`, `proguard` and so on.

But I only want to change the channel string.

how to speed up the execute. I had try to everything, also I don't
know how to do it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URF7p.png)

Packaging multiple apps had take some times.

I will be despairing.

Comment: Product flavors are just for changing the package name so that you can have multiple replica of same app. It would not make not affect much in your execution. It can be because of you are building releasing build always.

Answer (score 0):

The slowless has nothing to do with ProductFlavor. The moment you build with `-Release`, it can takes 3-5x more time than your usual debug build. That's because proguard obfuscation is an expensive task. If you only want to build for testing, try to build with `-Debug` instead. Otherwise, build only one Release flavor by executing `assembleARelease` or `assembleBRelease`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say it clearly. I want to package multiple apps at the same time with grade script.

Comment: When I execute the `assemble` command, the gradle will repeated execute the each task for one flavor. If i define 50 flavors, it means execute 50 times Life Circle.